# Set-Cookie header does not set cookie in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, http, internet-explorer, cookies, jersey

I'm trying to set a cookie server-side using the Set-Cookie header.

Using jersey the cookie is set server side like this:

```
NewCookie cookie  = new NewCookie("token", tokenValue, "/", "", 1, "", 3600, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000), false, false);
return Response.ok()
                .cookie(cookie)
                .build();
```

My response header in Chrome looks like this:

[image]

When I try to send another request to the server, to check if the cookie is send back, everything works as expected. The request header looks like this:

[image]

Firefox and Opera browsers also show the same behavior. Although, when I try Internet Explorer, there's another story...

Response headers of the first request:
[image]

Headers of the second request:
[image]

Basically there are no request headers, and the cookie is not set...
Am I doing something wrong, when I set the cookie? I have tried various solutions from other similar questions, but nothing seems to work...

**EDIT:**

Changed the IE Internet options by disabling protected mode and allowed all cookies, but still nothing...

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Trying it on different computers, I get mixed results. In some computers it works properly, and in some it doesn't. There must be some settings on the Internet Explorer that I am missing. Although, no matter what I try, I cannot get it to work on `localhost`...

**SOLUTION**

Apparently, as dabaicai commented there should not be any empty attribute-value fileds. when I created my cookie the `domain` and `comment` atrribute had empty values:

```
NewCookie cookie  = new NewCookie("token", tokenValue, "/", "", 1, "", 3600, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000), false, false);
```

I changed it to:

```
NewCookie cookie  = new NewCookie("token", tokenValue, "/", httpServletRequest.getServerName(), 1, "no-comment", 3600, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000), false, false);
```

And now everything works as expected in Internet Explorer too!

Comment: Have you [googled it](https://www.google.com.kh/?gws_rd=cr&ei=cgckWZ3KIIH60gSa56rADA#q=internet+explorer+not+sending+cookies) yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think because of the domain `localhost`,you can try visit the URL with 127.0.0.1,and then see the result.

Comment: Nope, not working... I already tried 127.0.0.1. I also set a different name for localhost in hosts file, and still nothing...

Comment: Do you visit the page on other computer?

Comment: You're right! When I visit the link form another computer, it works! But when I try localhost it fails....

Comment: The rfc6265 indicate If the attribute-value is empty, the behavior is undefined.So browser can discard the Domain.

Comment: You mean that if the comment of domain attributes have empty values, could cause a problem?